# Invalid parameter in Facebook marketing API

Tags: facebook, authorization, facebook-marketing-api

```
$video_data = new AdCreativeVideoData();
$video_data->setData(array(

  AdCreativeVideoDataFields::VIDEO_ID => $videoId,
  AdCreativeVideoDataFields::CALL_TO_ACTION => array(
    'value' => array(
      'page' => '209938349531555',
    ),
  ),
));


$object_story_spec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
$object_story_spec->setData(array(
  AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => '209938349531555',
  AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::VIDEO_DATA => $getId,
));

$creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_101365637166818');


$creative->setData(array(
  AdCreativeFields::NAME => 'Sample Creative',
  AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
));

$crtv=$creative->create();
```

This is the code I am using to for video ad.But I am getting this error:
"Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message 'Invalid parameter'"

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you initialize API?

   `Api::init(
       '<app_id>',
       '<app_secret>',
       '<facebook_access_token>'
   );`
2. In AdCreativeObjectStorySpec set data you have error

`AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::VIDEO_DATA => $getId`

change to:

`AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::VIDEO_DATA => $video_data`

3. Do you have linked Facebook app with the Facebook site?

[Page Subscribed Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps)

4. You don't have call to action type

`'type' => AdCreativeCallToActionTypeValues::LIKE_PAGE,`

5. Read Docs [Ad Creative Video Data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative-video-data/#Creating)

Comment: I initialized it. And changes $get_id to $video_data. But still getting the same error. What do you mean by "Do you have linked Facebook app with the Facebook site?" ?